# Sending an email without smtp_pass codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm trying to make a Sugestions/Reclamations form where the user need to complete with his email, subject and message.
The email will come to me, so i will always know the "to" email.

Normally i send an email like this:

```
$config = array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host'=>'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
                'smtp_port'=>465,
                'smtp_user' => 'mail@yahoo.com',
                'smtp_pass' => 'password',
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset'   => 'utf-8',
                'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
                'crlf' => "\r\n",
                'newline' => "\r\n",
            );
$this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->from('mail@yahoo.com','someText');
            $this->email->to($user_email);
            $this->email->subject('Some Subject');
            $this->email->message('Some message');
```

In this case i will not have user's email password so how can i send the email?I assume the password it's required.

Comment: You have to send it using your smtp account, not theirs.

Comment: Huh...so the email will be from me to me and they will need to complete 'email' field only to know to who i need to response?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can still set their email address as "from" and yours as "to", but you'll have to use your smtp user info and password.

Comment: I see
Well,post it as an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set their email address as "from" and yours as "to", but you'll have to use your smtp user info and password.